# Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported] Spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a small API on Spring boot, with which we can change USER's name/email/number. 
Everything is working OK, but  when I try to edit and save it, on the web it gives me:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you see this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 08 18:31:41 GET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

and in console:

Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

How can I fix it?

Spring BOOT:

```java
package com.example.demo.homePage;

import com.example.demo.user.User;
import com.example.demo.user.UserDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomePageApp{
    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    public HomePageApp(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String returnIndex(){
        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String userList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userDAO", userDAO.returnListOfUsers());

        return "personList";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String showUserByID(@PathVariable("id") int ID, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userDAO", userDAO.showUserByHisID(ID));

        return "userPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}/edit")
    public String editUser(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        model.addAttribute("userDAO", userDAO.showUserByHisID(id));

        return "edit";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String userUpdate(@ModelAttribute("userDAO") User user, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        userDAO.updateUser(id, user);

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/register")
    public String createNewPerson(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        return "register";
    }

    @PostMapping("/users/regDone")
    public String createNewUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model){
        userDAO.saveNewUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("userDAO", userDAO);

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>User Update</title>
</head>
<body>

<form th:method="PATCH" th:action="@{/users/{id}(id = ${userDAO.getID()})}" th:object="${userDAO}">
  <label for="name">Enter your Name: </label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="name"> <br>

  <label for="lastName">Enter your LastName: </label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName"> <br>

  <label for="email">Enter your Mail: </label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email"> <br>

  <label for="age">Enter your Mail: </label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{age}" id="age"> <br>

  <input type="submit" value="Update!">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do a `PATH` request and get *Request method 'POST' not supported* as eror message? Looks like your code does not fit to the error message

Comment: Yes, but as I know, 'PATH' will automatically generated to 'POST' after going to this site

Comment: then try `@PatchMapping("/users/{id}")` to `@PostMapping("/users/{id}")`